# How do you determine when user is clicking the end point of an edit sketch using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcobjects, editing, vb.net

I am using vb.net working on ArcObjects. One requirement is to pop up a toolbox once the user click the end point (double click the point under editing status). So I want to know how can I know when user clicking the end point. Is it possible?

By the way, will this possible by using python?

Comment: Are you listing to the edit events? The IEditEvents.OnSketchFinished Event should give you when the user has finished the sketch.

Comment: This is not possible using Python but, for future reference, when you have something extra to ask, please try to ask a new Question rather than a "supplementary".  The Q&A format works best with one question per Question.

Comment: This [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18420/how-to-make-sure-onsketchfinished-always-works) shows the basic syntax for listening out for an editor event. This example uses VBA so should be easy to transfer to a VB .net environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ArcGis add-in (version 10+).

To work with mouse clicks it's simplest to make a tool, but that means you have to do **all** the work and you can't change tools. For this you need to implement [ITool.OnMouseDown](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00430000007q000000) or [ITool.OnDblClick](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnDblClick_Method/00430000007m000000/) where the event work is all done for you.

If you want to use existing tools (edit, add feature, reshape..) and detect when the mouse is down then you need to listen for a specific event read [this about wiring events](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002p3000000).

I think that [IMapControlEvents2.OnMouseDown](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnMouseDown_Event/001600000268000000/) may help.